# Swap suddenly vanished from Debian?

Tags: debian, partition, fstab, swap, fdisk

Everything has been going fine for 6 months now until my swap suddenly vanished today. Now that I look into it, I find that my disk partitioning is a bit weird. What happened to it, and what should I do to recover it quickly without having to reinstall everything? (I need to finish a job before I do a fresh install again)

Here is my `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ede3c189-5d39-4f55-b263-0d6bcafc5d7b /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
# /dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
# /dev/sdc1       /media/usb1     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

(why is there "Ubuntu" there by the way?)

Here is the result of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000aabb9

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   8e  Linux LVM
```

As for lvm information, here is the output of `ls -l /dev/mapper`

```
total 0
crw------T 1 root root 10, 236 juin  29 07:28 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 juin  29 07:28 ubuntu--vg-root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 juin  29 07:28 ubuntu--vg-swap_1 -> ../dm-1
```

.. the output of `lvscan`

```
ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [294,10 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [3,74 GiB] inherit
```

.. and the output of `pvscan`

```
PV /dev/sda5   VG ubuntu-vg   lvm2 [297,85 GiB / 12,00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [297,85 GiB] / in use: 1 [297,85 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

.. and every day it looks more clear that we might have not wiped Ubuntu properly from my disk that night -_-

Is there a way I can quickly get my swap back before I get time to wipe all this?

Comment: as your / root and swap where configured in lvm please show an output of `lvscan` and `pvscan`. The ubuntu is the name of the volume group. Your installer should have named it that way. Check `ls -l /dev/mapper/` too if there still is a `ubuntu--vg-swap_1` node

Comment: Please run fdisk again but change the language: `sudo LC_ALL=C fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Also, we don't know why it says Ubuntu, that's probably what you installed :). Are you sure you installed Debian?

Comment: @ikrabbe Thank you for your help. See the edit for the output you asked for.

Comment: @terdon I am pretty sure this is what we intended to! :) But I wasn't informed that much about partitionning then. I had an Ubuntu install that I wanted to get rid off and moved to Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the swap device you can

```
swapon /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

If there is an error with that swap space, because it was destroyed somehow, you can reformat the swap device with

```
mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Check the related manual pages `swapon(1)` and `mkswap(1)` for more information.

Comment: Great. My swap is back even if I don't understand yet why my partitionning is such a mess, and I even have documentation now. Thanks a lot! ^ ^

Comment: @lago-lito It's quite common to put the swap space and the root partition into lvm. That's the first step towards a fully encrypted system. Also it offers later resizing of partitions, if there is some space left. I use a even more complex setup on my laptop. When the laptop is turned off, no one who doesn't know the disk password would be able to use that system even if he has full access to my hardware.